# How to convert integers to strings within a Structure array in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, integer, structure

I have failed so far to change integers to strings in a structure array "Type" that is part of a bigger structure EEG.event.type -- I attach a printscreen that shows the structure.

I tried with such functions as num2str, int2str, cellfun, but I think I still lack a basic understanding of programming in Matlab to write a workable script -- could you give me a hand?

[Printscreen--Matlab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZ7Af.png)

Thank you.

Comment: For clarification: are you referring to MATLAB's new string class (added in 2016b, I believe) or character arrays?

Comment: @Poelie -- I'm using Matlab R2015b, so it's character arrays. Basically, I want Matlab to read the data in EEG.event.type as characters(strings), e.g. " '11' " rather than numbers/integers " 11 "

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear, but from the screenshot it seems like event is a table within the EEG structure? If so this works for me.

```
% Create some mock data. 
EEG.event=table([1:41]','VariableNames',{'type'});

% To string array (MATLAB 2016b and later)
EEG.event.type=string(EEG.event.type);

% To character array (Any version) 
EEG.event.type=num2str(EEG.event.type);
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I'm using Matlab R2015b, and I did try the 

`EEG.event.type = num2str(EEG.event.type);`

before, but it always gives me the following error:

`Error using num2str
Too many input arguments.`

Comment: What type of variable is EEG.event and EEG.event.type?

Comment: EEG.event is a structure array, while EEG.event.type is a structure array field, i.e. 'type' is a field within the struct array of EEG.event. The 'type' field contains integer data (as demonstrated in the print screen).

Comment: I have managed to change individual rows from integers to string using the following code: `EEG.event(2).type=num2str(EEG.event(2).type);`. However, when I want to change all rows (`EEG.event(:).type`), it gives me an error: `too many input integers`